# How to make table cell page brake in Novacode?

Tags: novacode-docx

I need to make one big table and the cell does not start at a new page,
so one cell will be on 2 pages which I do not want, how can I prevent this?

I found this http://shaunakelly.com/word/styles/page-breaks-in-tables.html

But it does not seem to apply for C#.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a solution.
It seems that Novacode does not allow page break within cells (I think),
Or at least it is not clear to me how it is done.

My solution was, that instead of having one long table I made many tables, 
and using table.keepWithinNext() made my tables page breaking.

Using keepWithinNext() on my cells skewed the document or made errors.